# A "reverse" triangle inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

We all know the triangle inequality, for which $a + b > c$ if $a,b,c$ are lengths of triangle edges.

Is there any name for the reverse case, in which a "$\beta$" set of triangles satisfies

$$a + b < \beta c$$

for some fixed $\beta$?

Comment: The triangle inequality actually says $$|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$$ for any $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$. Looks like you are referring to the special case of an *actual* geometric triangle, not just the generalization. Not sure if this helps, but you can always choose $\beta = \frac{a+b}{c}+1$ to guarantee the reverse of what you are looking for. Assuming $a,b,c>0$.

Answer (score 0):

The reverse triangle inequality is [something different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).

Your inequality just define a "set of triangles", so I doubt that there exist some special well known name for this set. Also worth notice that for $\beta \leq 1$ there is no such triangle.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat unrelated to the $\beta$ you propose, but if the "regular" triangle inequality says "the sum of the lengths of two sides of a triangle must be no less than the length of the third side" (i.e. $|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|$) then there is a related statement, sometimes referred to as the "reverse" triangle inequality: "the *difference* of the lengths of two sides of a triangle must be no greater than the length of the third side", i.e.

$$
|a| - |b| \leq |a - b|.
$$

Of course, this estimate is symmetric in $a,b$, so you also have

$$
|b| - |a| \leq |b - a|,
$$

finally implying

$$
||a| - |b|| \leq |a - b|
$$