# Is there a reverse inequality for submultiplicativity and/or subadditivity of matrix norms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

let $A$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be two arbitrary square matrices. For all matrix norms, subadditivity

$\lVert A +B \rVert \leq \lVert A \rVert + \lVert B \rVert$

and, for certain matrix norms (like, e.g., the Frobenius norm), submultiplicativity

$\lVert A \cdot B \rVert \leq \lVert A \rVert \cdot \lVert B \rVert$

hold.

My question is if there are reverse formulations for these two inequalities, e.g.,

$c_1 \cdot \lVert A +B \rVert \geq \lVert A \rVert + \lVert B \rVert$

$c_2 \cdot\lVert A \cdot B \rVert \geq \lVert A \rVert \cdot \lVert B \rVert$

with positive constants $c_1, c_2$ (whatever value they may have, probably they will depend on $A$ and $B$), or maybe some inequalities with

$f_1(A,B)\geq \lVert A \rVert + \lVert B \rVert$

$f_2(A,B) \geq \lVert A \rVert \cdot \lVert B \rVert$,

where $f_1, f_2$ are some functions I do not (yet) know. Any solutions or ideas pointing to solutions will be greatly appreciated.

This question is somewhat related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165201/a-reverse-triangle-inequality) discussing reversing the triangle inequality for scalars.

Comment: What kind of inequality would you want if $A + B = 0$ or $AB = 0$? What you can say is that $||A + B|| \geq \left| \ ||A|| - ||B|| \ \right|$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; I would say if $A+B=0$ or $AB=0$, then the inequality should not be evaluated... Regarding the relation you gave, do you have a reference for it? It might indeed be useful, thanks!

Comment: It's an immediate consequence of the triangle inequality $||X + Y|| \leq ||X|| + ||Y||$, taking first $X = A + B, Y = - B$, and then $X = A + B, Y = - A$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I should have seen that from the general triangle inequality, sorry. What about the submultiplicativity? Basically, if both $A$ and $B$ have full rank, their product also has full rank and cannot equal the zero matrix

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm doubtful this can be accomplished in a sensible way.

Comment: For the "submultiplicativity", you can say, e.g., $\|AB\|\geq\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|\|B^{-1}\|}$. Note that this bound is sharp but the terms are unrelated to $\|A\|$ and $\|B\|$.